# How to filter a range of elements in d3js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I need to translate downwards all the elements below the one on which mouse is over. Currently I can filter the selection by using .filter. The following code can filter the selection for elements i>10. How do I use the current id of the mouseover element instead of '10'.
Or if there is a better way to shift the proceeding elements, that'll be great. 
Thanks

```
var bars = chart.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate(0,' + y(i) + ')';
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .filter(function(d,i ) { console.log(this);return i>10 })
            .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                return 'translate(0,' + (y(i)) + ')';
            });
    });
```

[image: gutenberg]
[Live Here](http://www.jaskirat.me/uploads/DataVis/gutenberg/)

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make it into an Accordian style bar chart. The following elements move down once you click on a particular bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    ...

d3.json("js/data/fortune2009.json", function(json) {

    var node = svg.data([json]).selectAll("g.node")
        .data(bubble.nodes); // filter here?

    node.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "q" + color(d.Profit) + "-9"; });

    node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; })
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.Company.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to training current and future readers of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

replace `i` in the return with `$(this).attr('id')` to get the moused-over element's id.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
        d3.select(this)
        .filter(function(d,i ) { console.log(this);return $(this).attr('id') >10 })
            .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
                return 'translate(0,' + (y(i)) + ')';
            });
    });
```

**[Update]** - if you see Lars' comment, he correctly points out that if the `id` you are looking for is contained in your `data` you can access it by simply (and more efficiently) by doing `d.id` rather than through the element's id attribute.

Comment: Or indeed simply `d.id`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff that would return `data.id` - which might not be the same thing as the elements id. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but I would assume that the ID is in the data.

Comment: Due to sort functions the Ids are not displayed in order. But I removed the sort for now and  this helped in filtering the data.  `.filter(function(d) { console.log(d.id);return i<d.id; })` . I'm not sure on how to translate the elements downwards.  Here is the current mouseover code 
`.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
    d3.selectAll('.bar')
        .filter(function(d) { console.log(d.id);return i<d.id; })
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(0,' + (y(i)) + ')';
}) `